# How i can redirect to different signout paths using Rails and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using rails3 and gem devise and i have two roles admin and customer and i want after user

sign out admin should redirect to different path and customer should redirect to different path

when sign out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your desired functionality by using devise method after sign_out path.

but before you define these methods in application helper.

```
def is_admin?(user)
  admin_role = Role.find(:first, :conditions => ["name = ?", "admin"])
  return user.roles.include?(admin_role)
end


def is_customer?(user)
  admin_role = Role.find(:first, :conditions => ["name = ?", "customer"])
  return user.roles.include?(admin_role)
end
```

After that include application helper in application controller and define this method

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if is_admin?(current_user)
    home_path = "/admin/users/sign_in"
  elsif is_customer?(current_user)
    home_path = "/customer"
  end
    respond_to?(home_path, true) ? send(root_path) : home_path
```

end

Hope it will work fine !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can override the **after_sign_out_path_for(resource)** method that devise uses. Just mention the logic or just the desired redirection path after checking the roles of your user in the method. The devise session's destroy action calls the redirection path through this method.

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  #logic
end
```

Hope this is helpful..

Answer (score 0):

The [Devise README](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/configuring-controllers) covers how to set up custom routes and controllers. In short you'll want to customize your routes for each model, e.g.:

```rb
devise_for :admins,    :controllers => { :sessions => "admins/sessions" }
devise_for :customers, :controllers => { :sessions => "customers/sessions" }
```

Then create the corresponding controllers and override `Devise::SessionsController#destroy`, e.g.:

```rb
class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def destroy
    super

    redirect_to ...
  end
end
```