# Conditional Route on sign_out using Devise with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am working on an app in which there is a model **User** with roles member and Admin.

As per requirement, I have to made two separate login pages for Admin and Member.

with `http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_login`

it goes to admin login page and with

`http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`

it goes to member login page.
Just after login I route them according to their roles to Admin panel or simple website for members.

But at time of logout both goes to 
`http://localhost:3000`

but I want admin to go to `http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_login`,
 while `http://localhost:3000` is fine for member's logout.

Is there a way to see User's Role at time of Sign_out and route them accordingly.

Comment: How would you know user is admin or member. Do you have any attributes set in database?

Comment: I have used rolify gem.
with current_user.has_role? :Admin, I can check them, but where to check this with devise

Answer (score 1):

You can define a after sign out path according to resource in application controller..

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  # Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path
  end
end
```

In `after_sign_out_for_for` method you can check user role and redirect to

For more details visit devise wiki [After Sign out path in devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out)

Comment: and how to check role here, resource.has_role? :Admin is giving error

Comment: Please see the argument send to after_sign_out_path_for. `resource_or_scope` is the variable there. and you are checking resource.has_role?. You need to check `resource_or_scope.has_role? :Admin`..or you have set resource ?

Comment: Same Issue with "resource_or_scope" too

Comment: `after_sign_out_path_for` receives a symbol, not a record - you will not get access to the user record that just logged out. See the doc comment on the method: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L217

Comment: I am not sure.. and have not use rolify gem with devise but trying to help you.. did you try this....`def after_sign_out_path_for
                                       current_user.has_role? :Admin
                                      end`

Comment: Hello mate yes, current user is not available and resource_or_scope will return symbol. This links may help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871612/how-i-can-redirect-to-diffrent-signout-paths-using-rails-and-devise

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try like this
Just save whatever path you want to redirect user after sign_out based on the role after login in session and use that session in after_sign_out_path_for method

```
after_filter :store_location

def store_location
  return unless session[:login_url].blank? 
  session[:login_url] = current_user.admin? ? admin_path : other_user_path
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource) 
  session[:login_url] || request.referer || root_path
end
```

there are one other way just overwrite devise sessoin controller and redirect user from there based on role

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" } # etc

# sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def destroy
    #login_path = set path in a variable based on user role before sing_out
    #code to sign out 
    #
   redirect_to login_path
  end

end
```

Comment: thanks man, but I tried this type of solution, it seems them devise signout cleared all sessions

Comment: @shadow solution works for you, I have not tested my solution just added code based on the knowledge, Yes you are right device remove all session on signout

Comment: No, Shadow solution is also not working because at that time I just have a symbol of user in form of resource_or_scope instead of user's object. So can't check role

Comment: Admin have access of those pages those are not accessible by other user ?

Comment: I think you just redirect user to last page from their they are logout it will redirect user back to their login page

Answer (score 0):

Are the pages that they are clicking on the logout links different for admins and users? If so, you could check the request.referrer property in your after_sign_out_path method and route accordingly.

BTW if you are routing them to the right pages after logging in then why do you need separate login pages? you may want to just have one login page for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You can also leave it `config.sign_out_via =: get => config/initializers/devise.rb` is not the best way but solved for me.